# train_test_split for multiple targets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have multiobjective problem. I have two targets `ylo` and `yhi` sharing the same features `x`:

```
x = np.array([[0,1,2],[2,3,4]])
ylo = np.array([10,11])
yhi = np.array([12,13])
```

is there a way to split the data to get `x_train`, `x_test`,`ylo_train`,`ylo_test`,`yhi_train`,`yhi_test` from `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`? Or is there another function that's better?

So far I have to do the splitting twice:

```
X_train, X_test, ylo_train, ylo_test = train_test_split(
    X, ylo,test_size=0.19, random_state=1)

_, _, yhi_train, yhi_test = train_test_split(
    X, yhi,test_size=0.19, random_state=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put them in a data frame and just train on the individual columns

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,
pd.DataFrame({'ylo':ylo,'yhi':yhi}),test_size=0.19, random_state=1)
```